# Magento: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

Tags: jquery, magento, fancybox

I have a some problems with my website:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
    at jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js:18
    at jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js:46
```

It is a console log.
I had try many solutions, changing code `$.browser.msie` to another code and more,and more... But when I'm changing my file : `jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js` from `$.browser.msie` to `navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'` everything work, but when I try to change `jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js` it's not work at all... I had add a migrate jQuery into my `page.phtml`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I repaird this problem, thanks for your response.